# What is the recommended stable version of SlickGrid to use for deployment

Tags: slickgrid

Is there a stable version of SlickGrid that should be used for deployment or is it recommended practice to take a snapshot of the github repository and use that for deployment? I see a number of tags but none that is very recent (e.g., tag *2.02* is 7 months old and there have been lots of commits since then).

Up to now I have been tracking the SlickGrid github repository for development but I'd like to fix to a version before deploying. It would be nice if there was a recommended stable package download available (maybe there is and I haven't come across it?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SlickGrid 2.1 is available as a release on github](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/releases/tag/2.1) - official mailing list announcement [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/slickgrid/ypIS60kQ06U).